# window.location broken on iOS 9

Tags: html, uiwebview, ios9, window.location

We have a bug in our app that loads UIWebView with Javascript. We use `window.location` to pass data to the UIWebView and it doesn't work anymore in ios9.

It's very similar to the AngularJS bug at https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109 and https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c but we don't use Angular.

Our analysis shows the problem is communication between the app and UIWebView. We use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"` and it seems to be an issue.

We opened a ticket to Apple Developer Technical Support but they kindly suggested us to submit a bug report.

Currently our app doesn't work and we need to find a workaround to solve the situation.

Comment: Well stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString works for me to set global vars, so you could pass info to global variables or to specific js classes via  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. I'm not sure what your doing with window.location so maybe elaborate on that.